# How to rewrite iand to conform with newer versions of gfortran

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I am working with an older Fortran code and during compilation I get many different error messages, some of the of the following format:

```
if(iand(n_jz2_max,1).eq.0) then
                        1
Error: Arguments of ‘iand’ have different kind type parameters at (1)
```

where `n_jz2_max` is an `integer*4`.

I understand that the `iand` no longer supports parameters of different kind type, but I do not know how to change the code to be able to compile.

I tried to compile the code with an older version of gfortran, but this is not an option for me. The Ubuntu version I have installed does not allow me to install older versions of gfortran. Another solution would be to install an older Ubuntu version, but I prefer to make a try and change the code.

---

Update:

Thank you everyone for your answers. Indeed I was using compiler options like -fdefault-integer-8 which led to errors. This is how I was compiling the code: (The include option was added because the code depended on a file located inside a folder named "include".)

$ mpif90 -f90=gfortran -c -w -I include -O2 -fdefault-integer-8 -o build/mm_1.16.o source/mm_1.16.f90

After many unsuccessful tries, I ended up removing all mpich versions from my laptop and installing the newest version. I changed the compilation options to

$ mpif90 -c -w -I include -O2 -o build/mm_1.16.o source/mm_1.16.f90

and the code compiled without any issues.

Comment: Need to see the actual code and actual error message and compiler options used.  If `n_jz2_max` is an `integer*4`, then it and `1` have the same kind type parameter.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. As steve noted, we need more code, see [mcve] for generoc instructions how to make a suitable code sample. We should be able to reproduce your problem from your code. Please also use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions. Good tags are very important.

Comment: Sigh, we need to see that actual declaration of `n_jz2_max` and the command line options you are using.  The error you show is simply not possible with gfortran if `n_jz2_max` is `integer*4`.

Comment: Also, as steve noted, the compiler flags used to compile your code are very important. Are you using options such as `-fdefault-integer-8` somewhere? We need the exact command you use and the full error message you got. You are speaking about different versions of Fortran. That is not correct. It is about different versions of the gfortran compiler (a part of GCC) that diagnose more errors with more recent versions. Please note that it is possible to compile any old version of GCC with gfortran from source from gcc.gnu.org, but it would not be the recommended, it is better to fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mention, this shouldn't happen with the default compilation options. You're likely using `-fdefault-integer-8` or something like that.

What you can do to make sure that the kind of the literal `1` and the `0` matches the kind of `n_jz2_max` could be something like

```
integer, parameter :: q = kind(n_jz2_max)
...
if(iand(n_jz2_max, 1_q) .eq. 0_q) then
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers. Indeed I was using compiler options like -fdefault-integer-8 which led to errors. Of course, I was just following the Makefile of the code. This is how I was compiling the code: (The include option was added because the code depended on a file located inside a folder named "include".)

$ mpif90 -f90=gfortran -c -w -I include -O2 -fdefault-integer-8 -o build/mm_1.16.o source/mm_1.16.f90

After many unsuccessful tries, I ended up removing all mpich versions from my laptop and installing the newest version. I changed the compilation options to

$ mpif90 -c -w -I include -O2 -o build/mm_1.16.o source/mm_1.16.f90

and the code compiled without any issues.

Comment: Note that the `-fdefault-integer-8` option might have been there because it is necessary to have the larter integers in some circumstances. If you encounter bad behaviour, it could be connected. Only the author of the code can know for sure. Of course there are much better ways how to code that, but you have to work with what you have.